# Cut between each Level of a tree (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Im struggling with a problem. To show the different levels of a tree more clearly, I want to draw a cut (i.e. a straight line that cuts all edges from Level i to Level j ) between each level in a tree.
Can you help me with that?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=6mm]

\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,circle,minimum size=0.5em, inner sep=1pt]

 \node {r}

    child {node {\tiny{1}}}

    child {node {\tiny{1}}

    child {node {\tiny{2}}

    child {node {\tiny{3}}}

    child {node {\tiny{3}}}

    child {node {\tiny{3}}}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please add the necessary header information so your code compiles.  If `beamer` is not essential to the problem, then remove the `frame` commands.

Comment: This doesn't compile, not even if I put in the beamer document class and load package tikz.

Comment: By cut, do you mean leave a gap?

Comment: `\tiny` does not take an argument. `{\tiny 1}` is what you should use here. However, `\tiny` is going to be almost impossible for most of your audience to read, so the content is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. Also you provide only code snipped with depreciated syntax for defining node style. Consequently, the following MWE is based on my guessing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=0.75em, 
                     inner sep=1pt, font=\tiny},
   level distance = 6mm,
   level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 6mm},
                        ]
\node {r}
    child {node (n1) {1}}
    child {node {2}
        child {node (n2) {2}}
        child {node      {3}}
        child {node      {3}}
        child {node (n5) {5}}
            };
\draw[dashed, shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] 
    ([yshift=1.5mm] n1.north)       -- ([yshift=1.5mm] n1.north -| n5.east);
\draw[dashed, shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm]
    ([yshift=1.5mm] n2.north -| n1) -- ([yshift=1.5mm] n2.north -| n5.east); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result is very small image:

[image]